# What is CloudPhotoLibraryErrorDomain Code=25?

Tags: ios, icloud, photokit

We are trying to download assets from iCloud using PHCachingImageManager: requestImageDataForAsset: options: resultHandler,
however we encounter the following error on production:
Domain=CloudPhotoLibraryErrorDomain Code=25 “Record ***the_record_id*** does not exist”

It seems that it appears what trying to download iCloud asset after application launch.

Can anyone provide more info on this error?
What is the cause to trigger such an error?
Is this error is fatal or temporary?

Comment: Looks like you might receive this error when iCloud storage is full (no free space left) and you try to request some file (in my case it's a video)